# Category name in order email Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I would like to know if there is a way to add the product category to the order email that is sent to the seller.

Prestashop version: 1.7.6.9

Comment: Do you mean the description of the default category? Can you access to the controller or only to the pdf tpl file?

Comment: I'm talking about adding the product category field to the products table of the email body, that is sent to the seller when a new order is placed

Comment: I'm sorry, but i asked something different. A product can have multiple categories associated. Do you want the default one? And then you have to answer to the second question. Based on that i can provide a correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There are 3 product categories, and one of them has subcategories, so I guess it's not the default one I need to display.